# *.tlb file -- per version of Visual Studio?

Tags: winapi, com

I haven't done COM in over 10 years so I was wondering:

When I utilize a 3rd party COM based SDK by importing its TLB file -- is it their responsibility to release a version of TLB for each version of visual studio I use their SDK with? or is TLB a "flat" binary file that fits all versions of visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type library format is standardized and independent of any tool that reads it, including Visual Studio.  Tools use ITypeLib and ITypeInfo to read one, implemented by Oleaut32.dll